How to pass bot check/capture for registration on forum.videolan.org forum?
At the end of account registration there is check against bots:

Confirmation of registration
SEO or Spam attempts will cloud blacklist your IP and email from
10000+ other places. Do not put any link in your profile or signature.
You have been warned. To continue registration enter -d28- below,
spammers will enter "I agree" to continue: This question is a means of
preventing automated form submissions by spambots.

I tried to enter:

-d28-
d28
-d28- below
d28- below
I agree
-d28- below, spammers will enter "I agree" to continue:
-d28- below, spammers will enter "I agree" to continue: This question is a means of preventing automated form submissions by spambots.

Nothing is working.
Error messages are the following:

No soup for you! It looks like you have been flagged as a spammer.
You have provided an invalid answer to the question.
You have provided an invalid answer to the question. You have exceeded the maximum number of registration attempts for this session. Please try again later.

What is expected to enter from this kinds of captures? Am I doing something wrong or there just a bug on server side?
This is videolan forum: https://forum.videolan.org

Because of bugs it is also not possible now to create account for their bugtracker here - https://code.videolan.org
Errors are the following:

Your account is pending approval from your GitLab administrator and hence blocked. Please contact your GitLab administrator if you think this is an error.
Signing in using your GitLab.com account without a pre-existing GitLab account is not allowed. Create a GitLab account first, and then connect it to your GitLab.com account.
Signing in using your GitHub account without a pre-existing GitLab account is not allowed. Create a GitLab account first, and then connect it to your GitHub account.

So I cannot write to their support team directly.

Answer got here: How to pass bot check/capture for registration on forum.videolan.org forum? : r/VLC
